# PySpark throws a Py4JJavaError when I try to initialize a SparkSession

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I just installed pyspark on my Jupyter notebook and tried running a simple line of code

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('MoviePractice').getOrCreate()
```

This throws a Py4JJavaError where it says

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$ (in unnamed module @0xe1de817) cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.nio.ch to unnamed module @0xe1de817
```

I had read a few solutions on similar questions where they said if I installed a certain jdk  on conda it would work but it didn't do the trick and I'm still stuck here.
Tried this:

```
conda install -c cyclus java-jdk
```

And this:

```
conda install -c conda-forge openjdk
```

Any help would be appreciated and I apologize if there is already an answer to this question and I didn't find it.